# Error in login page

Tags: acumatica

Can you please help me to figure out below issue which I faced while logging in.

An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = MsmqPrimaryNotificationQueue (DelegateActivator), Services = [PX.Data.PushNotifications.IPrimaryNotificationQueueWriter], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = ExternallyOwned ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = MsmqPrimaryNotificationQueue (DelegateActivator), Services = [PX.Data.PushNotifications.IPrimaryNotificationQueueWriter], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Message Queue service is not available. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)

Comment: I rebuild the website and issue got resolved, but still, anyone can help why this will happen.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an issue related with Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ) for Acumatica. To properly configure these settings please view the documentation on Page 57 relating to these services [here.](http://acumatica-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/builds/2017R2/PDF/AcumaticaERP_InstallationGuide.pdf)

Comment: I had to add the line <add key="EnablePushNotifications" value ="false" /> to my webconfig because it was missing, but that solved the issue.